# I just cannot understand EC2 pricing for on-demand instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

OK,
I am feeling really dumb right now.
I just can't figure out this thing..
I intend to run a server which will be on constantly 24/7 (no stopping/terminating on my side).
However the actual resource-use will be intermittent (idle 90% of the time).
Will that count as 24 hours a day of usage, or do they look at actual resource use?
Thanks guys

Comment: This is really a question you should be asking Amazon, not Server Fault. Amazon can change their pricing any time they wish, and any answers we give will only be valid until such time as Amazon changes pricing policies...

Comment: Amazon does change usage prices from time to time (so far, prices have gone down), but they've never changed their overall pricing policy of charging per hour per server type. And changing the policy at this point would likely lead to a customer revolt since customers have built their systems around this policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon EC2 servers are charged for each hour you use them. So a Small server in the us-east zone will cost 13 cents/hour or .13 * 24 * 30 = $93.60/month. It doesn't matter if you're using 10% of the CPU or 100%, it's the same hourly rate. If you have a long-term need for compute resources, you can save money by purchasing a one year or three year reserved instance. (by paying an upfront fee to "reserve" the instance, you can pay a lower hourly rate).

You'll also pay 12 cents per GB of outbound bandwidth (first GB is free, prices get cheaper above 10TB of data transfer)

Additionally, you'll pay for storage, if you have 100GB of storage allocated for the server, you'll pay 10 cents/GB-month, or 100 * .10  = $10/month for that storage.

You also pay $0.10 per million I/O requests. That's a bit harder to estimate, but tends to be minimal unless your server is doing a lot of I/O. You can minimize this cost by moving high I/O files to ephemeral block storage or even a tempfs memory based filesytem to reduce EBS disk I/O's.

The pricing is detailed here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

And they have a usage cost calculator here: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

---

If you have well defined peak and off-peak usage hours, you can save money by scaling your server usage to meet demand.

For example, one simple way to do this if you can stand some downtime, is to restart your server as a larger instance in the morning to cover peak demand, then restart it again as a smaller instance  in the evening to handle the slow, off-peak hours. You can script this by using the AWS API.

To avoid downtime, you could use an AWS load balancer (there is a fee for this) and have 2 server instances - start up the big one during peak time and then shut down the small server, then during off-peak,  start up your small server and then shut down the big one.

AWS also provides ways to [monitor your server load and automatically scale your servers up and down to meet load](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/), but this is probably overkill for a small site.